# Differenze tra gli aggettivi "professionale" e "professionista" per qualificare una persona

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, difference, adjectives

Ho guardato alle voci ["professionista"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/professionista/) e ["professionale"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/professionale) del vocabolario Treccani. Tuttavia, non mi è chiara la differenza tra questi due vocaboli quando sono adoperati come aggettivi per qualificare una persona che svolge una determinata professione.

Per esempio, se una donna lavora come tradutrice, cosa dovrei dire?

- È una tradutrice professionale.
- È una tradutrice professionista.

C'è qualche differenza di uso o di significato tra queste due frasi?

Il vocabolario Treccani indica che l'aggettivo "professionale" usato per qualificare persone è "non comune":

> **c.** non com. Di persona che, nell’esercizio del proprio mestiere, attività o professione, mostra particolare preparazione, serietà ed efficienza

Quindi, devo capire che "professionale" di solito non si usa o non si dovrebbe usare per qualificare una persona?

In ogni caso, ricercando su Google espressioni come "fotografo professionale" o "nuotatore professionale" si trovano parecchie occorrenze, ma forse si tratta di siti web non affidabili, non so.

Ho visto che il Treccani fa una definizione molto simile del termine "professionista", ma in questo caso si tratta di un "uso comune":

> **c**. Nell’uso com., chi svolge la propria attività lavorativa, qualunque essa sia, con particolare abilità e competenza: *quel calzolaio è un vero p.*; anche in funzione di attributo: *il furto è stato certamente opera di ladri p*.

Comment: Qualche professionista potrebbe comportarsi in modo non professionale; un non professionista può essere professionale. “Traduttrice professionale” mi suona di anglismo.

Comment: Tra l'altro, se vedi la voce del Treccani che citi, l'uso di “professionale” riferito a una persona esiste ma è raro: la maggior parte delle volte si dice di un modo di fare, un'attività, un albo, un tipo di formazione e così via.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG. Ma allora, dire  «non è stato professionale» intendendo che qualcuno non ha svolto il suo lavoro con serietà non è comune?  La voce «professionale» del Treccani dice «non com. Di persona che, nell’esercizio del proprio mestiere, attività o professione, mostra particolare preparazione, serietà ed efficienza».

Comment: @egreg: Cosa significa "un non professionista può essere professionale"?  Secondo il Treccani, "professionista" può significare "chi svolge la propria attività lavorativa, qualunque essa sia, con particolare abilità e competenza" e anche "professionale" può avere questo significato, ma è un uso "non comune" (e si riferisce al "proprio mestiere, attività o professione").

Comment: @Charo: Il contrario di “professionista” è spesso “dilettante”, ma di base vuol dire solo che il primo è pagato per fare quella cosa e ne trae da vivere, e il secondo no. Quindi un professionista potrebbe agire in modo dilettantesco (un elettricista che monta male un impianto), mentre un dilettante potrebbe agire in modo professionale.

Comment: Questo lo capisco, @DaG, ma il "non com" del Treccani mi confonde. Devo intendere che, nel tuo secondo esempio, potrei dire "quella persona agisce in modo professionale", mentre invece "quella persona è professionale" non sarebbe comune?

Comment: @Charo: Non so che cosa intendano di preciso con “non com.”. Direi che l'uso prevalente di “professionale” sia per definire – come dicevo in un altro commento – corsi, atteggiamenti, attività etc., ma non c'è niente che non vada nel dirlo di una persona. De Mauro e Zingarelli non marcano in modo speciale quest'uso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Professionista**: chi svolge una attività come professione, come sua attività primaria e che da essa trae guadagno; si contrappone quindi a dilettante.

**Professionale**: aggettivo che significa "relativo alla professione", ma che può assumere il senso "di persona che, nell’esercizio di una attività, mostra particolare preparazione, serietà ed efficienza" [(liberamente tratto da Treccani.it)](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/professionale)

Quindi se una donna lavora come traduttrice, sicuramente è una traduttrice *professionista*;
se svolge il suo lavoro in maniera svogliata e imprecisa, non è *professionale*;
se lo fa con particolare serietà, è *professionale*;

se una persona fa il traduttore per diletto, non è un *professionista*, ma se svolge la sua attivtà con serietà ed efficienza, è un traduttore *professionale*.

Comment: Tutto giusto, ma personalmente mi suonerebbe meglio dire che quella persona agisce in modo professionale etc., anziché dire direttamente che la persona stessa è professionale.

Comment: Capisco perfettamente cosa vuoi dire, @DaG, cioè che spesso si  usa "professionale" nella locuzione "lavorare (o agire) in modo professionale", ma spero che converrai con me, che se devi consigliarmi un tuo amico che taglia bene i capelli (non professionista), preferirai dire "Te lo consiglio, Marco è professionale", rispetto a "Te lo consiglio, Marco agisce in modo professionale"

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @Nicola. Tuttavia, secondo quello che riporta il Treccani  (la marca "non com"), devo capire che questo uso di "professionale" non è comune?

Comment: Per @Charo, a mio avviso, è un uso comunissimo.

Comment: @Nicola: Non c'è niente di sbagliato nell'attribuire direttamente a una persona “professionale” come aggettivo. Forse, di Marco, mi verrebbe da dire che “lavora in modo professionale”, ma sono sfumature (dipende dal contesto, persino dal lavoro di cui stiamo parlando etc.).

Comment: Concordo con @DaG: uno è professionale *in qualcosa*, spesso nel modo di agire. Eviterei l'anglismo “è un traduttore professionale” per indicare che non lo fa di professione: “non è un traduttore professionista, ma è molto professionale”.