# Le espressioni "È un'evidenza che" e "È di tutta evidenza che" richiedono il congiuntivo?

Tags: word-usage, subjunctive-mood

Devo usare il congiuntivo con le espressioni «È un'evidenza che […]» e «È di tutta evidenza che […]»?

Comment: Senza toccare la questione del modo verbale da usare, mi suonano un po' strani come modi per iniziare una frase. “Evidenza” significa semplicemente “l'essere evidente”, la qualità di ciò che è evidente, e quindi personalmente non saprei come possa continuare una frase che inizia con “È un'evidenza che”. Per esempio “che Gino è/sia onesto” può essere evidente, palese etc., ma non “un'evidenza”. E, sempre personalmente, il secondo incipit mi suona un po' legnoso. Io direi “è evidente che”, magari rafforzandolo con qualche avverbio. Il tutto a mio modesto avviso, come si suol dire.

Comment: @DaG Sembra linguaggio da legali.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Potresti indicare il contesto in cui vorresti usare tali frasi?

Comment: @DaG:  «"[...] Non c'è un'evidenza che ci dica che chi è stato infetto non possa fare dopo il vaccino, in teoria chiunque può fare il vaccino": lo ha detto in conferenza stampa in diretta Facebook il direttore generale della prevenzione del ministero della Salute, Gianni Rezza» (https://stream24.ilsole24ore.com/video/italia/rezza-infettati-non-esclusi-vaccini-ma-ci-sono-priorita/AD1PHV6?refresh_ce=1) (ho aggiunto l'apostrofo mancante).

Comment: Invece: «In questo calore sicuro c'è un'evidenza che mi appaga» ([*Donne esemplari: Voci dal novecento letterario italiano Vol. 1*](https://books.google.es/books?id=YEvzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT337&dq=%22%C3%88+un%27evidenza+che+mi%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbtpz1iNXuAhUgAWMBHSZ4Dh0Q6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%88%20un'evidenza%20che%20mi%22&f=false)).

Comment: Anche: «[...] l'esperienza è un'evidenza che si presenta puramente nel mondo [...]» (https://books.google.es/books?id=ldQG9I98UCEC&q=%22%C3%A8+un%27evidenza+che%22&dq=%22%C3%A8+un%27evidenza+che%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbv9LNitXuAhX5DWMBHcniCW8Q6AEwCHoECAUQAQ) e «È un'evidenza che concerne propriamente gli snodi interattivi dell'ipertesto [...]» (https://books.google.es/books?id=khqSAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%C3%A8+un%27evidenza+che%22&dq=%22%C3%A8+un%27evidenza+che%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz-8TQi9XuAhUoxoUKHdsQDns4ChDoATAEegQIBRAB).

Comment: Gli esempi di "è di tutta evidenza che" che sono riuscita a trovare su Google Libri sono tutti ottocenteschi.

Comment: @Charo: L'uso contemporaneo (come nella citazione dal funzionario del ministero) è pesantemente influenzato dall'inglese _evidence_ che ha però un uso e un significato diversi, più simile a “prova” e simili. D'altronde, sulla spinta di varie discipline _evidence-based_ (che di per sé sono sacrosante), questo uso si sta diffondendo anche in italiano. [segue]

Comment: Sull'italiano ottocentesco non so abbastanza (forse c'entra il francese, ma tiro a indovinare). In generale, sarà uno di quei casi di confine, come “alternativa” che a rigore è l'insieme delle possibili opzioni ma si usa anche per ognuna delle opzioni, e molti altri.

Comment: Ho trovato la frase in un esercizio sull'utilizzo del congiuntivo:
«È un'evidenza che Maria sia spaventata da quel incidente.»

Comment: @sid_com: Francamente, se la leggessi non sarei sicuro se l'autore intendeva “È ovvio che Maria è spaventata etc.” oppure “[La cosa di cui parliamo] fa pensare che Maria sia spaventata etc.”. E non lo troverei un modo elegante di dire nessuna delle due cose.

Comment: @DaG: Quindi, nell'uso odierno, si tratterebbe di un calco dall'inglese in frasi come, per esempio, la seguente che ho tratto di questo interessante [articolo della rivista *Nature*](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00251-4?utm_source=Nature+Briefing&utm_campaign=65657f8ef0-briefing-dy-20210201&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_c9dfd39373-65657f8ef0-46069074): "there is limited evidence of transmission through fomites. [..]"?

Comment: Sì, @Charo, e aggiungo che le norme editoriali per collaboratori e traduttori del mensile _Le Scienze_ mette, sotto “da usare il meno possibile”, tra altre voci, “evidenza (al posto di ‘prova’)”.

Comment: Grazie, @DaG: la tua esperienza come traduttore professionista (ho dovuto rileggere [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/differenze-tra-gli-aggettivi-professionale-e-professionista-per-qualificare) per sapere quale aggettivo usare) ha un grande valore su Italian.SE (anche questo è un calco dell'inglese?). Adesso mi accorgo che lo stesso fenomeno è entrato nella lingua catalana. Mio marito ha cominciato a dire spesso "non hi ha evidències de contagi per contacte amb superfícies", mentre si dovrebbe dire "no hi ha proves de contagi per contacte amb superfícies".

Comment: A proposito di questa discussione mi sembrerebbe interessante una domanda sull'uso che si fa 
di queste espressioni nell'italiano odierno e sulla convenienza di sostituirle con altre genuinamente italiane.

Comment: @sid_com:  Ci potreste indicare qual è la fonte dell'esercizio che hai menzionato?

Comment: @egreg: Ma i legali non dovrebbero dire anche "prove" al posto di "evidenze"?

Comment: @Charo: http://www.impariamoitaliano.com/cong31.htm

Comment: @Charo Perché? Uno degli stilemi è “se qualcosa si può dire in breve, lo si allunga”. Quindi “è evidente che” diventa “è di tutta evidenza che”.

Comment: @Charo: Una domanda sull'uso di calchi dall'inglese e dei loro corrispondenti in “buon” italiano sarebbe molto interessante, ma andrebbe formulata in modo da prevenire risposte troppo soggettive, altrimenti si rischiano interventi sul fatto che “suona meglio così” o che “ho sempre fatto cosà”.

Comment: Non so se sono riuscita a [farlo](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13465/), @DaG.

Comment: @sid_com:  Come persona che ha quasi sempre imparato l'italiano da autodidatta, ti consiglierei di non dare piena fiducia a certi siti web.

Comment: @DaG: Aggiungo che ho parlato con mio marito e anche lui è completamente d'accordo che nell'esempio che ho menzionato in catalano dovrebbe dirsi "prova" al posto di "evidència", che non ha questa accezione nei dizionari della lingua catalana. Purtroppo, però, lui stesso mi ha fornito qualche esempio di uso di "evidència" al posto di "prova" in documenti ufficiali del governo catalano.

Answer (score 1):

Per definizione il congiuntivo è il modo del dubbio, della possibilità e della soggettività. Quello che tu vuoi esprimere invece è una certezza lampante, quindi seguendo la logica, è bene usare l'indicativo.

Faccio un esempio

- è chiaro che Francesca e Luca stanno bene insieme (esprimo certezza)
- non mi è chiaro se Francesca e Luca stiano bene insieme (esprimo dubbio)

Ho preferito usare "è chiaro" perché mi suona meglio, però l'idea di base è certezza implica indicativo, dubbio/possibilità/augurio implica congiuntivo.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!