# Sull'uso di "evidenza" in espressioni come "(non) ci sono evidenze", "(non) c'è un'evidenza" o "evidenze scientifiche"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, english-comparison, latin

In una recente discussione nei commenti a  [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13463/), si è menzionato che il termine "evidenza" usato in espressioni come "ci sono evidenze", "non ci sono evidenze", "c'è un'evidenza", "non c'è un'evidenza", "alla luce delle evidenze", "evidenze scientifiche", ecc. sembra un calco dall'inglese *evidence* in frasi come, per esempio, questa, tratta di questo [articolo della rivista *Nature*](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00251-4?utm_source=Nature+Briefing&utm_campaign=65657f8ef0-briefing-dy-20210201&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_c9dfd39373-65657f8ef0-46069074):

> A WHO spokesperson told *Nature* that "there is limited evidence of transmission through fomites. [...]"

Ecco alcuni esempi che ho trovato in rete (grassetto mio):

> «"[...] **Non c'è un'evidenza** che ci dica che chi è stato infetto non possa fare dopo il vaccino, in teoria chiunque può fare il vaccino": lo ha detto in conferenza stampa in diretta Facebook il direttore generale della prevenzione del ministero della Salute, Gianni Rezza» (da [*Il sole 24 ore*](https://stream24.ilsole24ore.com/video/italia/rezza-infettati-non-esclusi-vaccini-ma-ci-sono-priorita/AD1PHV6?refresh_ce=1), ho aggiunto l'apostrofo mancante).

> «In questo calore sicuro **c'è un'evidenza** che mi appaga» (dal libro [*Donne esemplari: Voci dal novecento letterario italiano Vol. 1*](https://books.google.es/books?id=YEvzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT337&dq=%22%C3%88+un%27evidenza+che+mi%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbtpz1iNXuAhUgAWMBHSZ4Dh0Q6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%88%20un%27evidenza%20che%20mi%22&f=false)).

> «In queste pagine facciamo chiarezza sulle fake news più diffuse, smentendole **alla luce delle evidenze disponibili**» (dal [sito web del Ministero della Salute](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/archivioFakeNewsNuovoCoronavirus.jsp)).

> «Tutte le informazioni sono verificate dagli esperti del ministero della Salute e/o dell’Istituto superiore di sanità e **sono basate su evidenze scientifiche**, normative, documentazioni nazionali e internazionali disponibili alla data di pubblicazione di ogni notizia»
> (dal [sito web del Ministero della Salute](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/archivioFakeNewsNuovoCoronavirus.jsp)).

> «Attualmente **non ci sono evidenze** che la mutazione del virus rilevata in Gran Bretagna possa avere effetti sull'efficacia della vaccinazione anti Covid-19» (dal [sito web del Ministero della Salute](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/archivioFakeNewsNuovoCoronavirus.jsp)).

> «Dall'altra, per quanto riguarda la coesione territoriale invece **ci sono evidenze di** una crescita consistente del numero di poli di sviluppo» (dal libro [*Federalismo e crescita: è possibile una relazione virtuosa?*](https://books.google.es/books?id=23HazjipdnIC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%22ci+sono+evidenze+di+una%22&source=bl&ots=1ntK0sNgEU&sig=ACfU3U3kGXCiuImmM9Rr2R6wL7FUnwQ2KA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilpuqo2tfuAhXFnFwKHQ5FAngQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ci%20sono%20evidenze%20di%20una%22&f=false)).

Non sono sicura che la parola "evidenza" nella frase tratta dal libro *Donne esemplari: Voci dal novecento letterario italiano Vol. 1* si usi con lo stesso significato degli altri esempi che ho citato. Il fatto è che, secondo le tre accezioni riportate nel Treccani, [*evidenza*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/evidenza/) non mi sembra un termine adatto ai contesti di queste frasi, tranne forse quella tratta da questo libro (a dire il vero, non sono sicura sul significato del vocabolo in questa frase).

Comunque sia, le mie domande sono: fino a che punto questo uso si è diffuso nell'italiano contemporaneo? È consigliabile
sostituire questo tipo di espressioni con altre ritenute genuinamente italiane? Se è così, con quali?

## Aggiornamento:

Tenendo conto del fatto che "evidenza" viene dal
dal lat. *evidentia*,
ho fatto un po' di ricerca su cosa succede in altre lingue romanze che conosco di più. Sono riuscita a trovare [questo articolo](https://www.raco.cat/index.php/TreballsSCBiologia/article/download/16032/336327/),  pubblicato nella rivista [*Treballs de la Societat Catalana de Biologia*](http://revistes.iec.cat/index.php/TSCB/issue/view/4521/showToc), nel numero col titolo  *Comunicar ciència*,  su problemi della traduzione al catalano di testi scientifici in inglese. L'articolo fa un elenco di falsi amici, tra cui appare appunto "evidence" e si afferma che dovrebbe essere tradotto in catalano come "prova" (non come "evidència").

E anche la lingua spagnola ha un problema analogo,  come si menziona nell'articolo ["Cuestiones socio-científicas y pensamiento crítico: Una propuesta para cuestionar las pseudociencias"](http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/ted/n46/0121-3814-ted-46-81.pdf) di Jordi Solbes, professore di Didattica delle scienze presso l'Universitat di València:

> Los trabajos sobre cuestiones socio-científicas (CSC) empiezan a surgir [...]. [...] Esto completa el tema de las CSC con aspectos procedimentales como el uso de *evidence*, españolizado como evidencias, cuando la traducción más adecuada sería pruebas [...].

È lo stesso in italiano? C'è qualche voce autorevole che raccomandi sostituire "evidenza" con "prova" in contesti simili a quelli degli esempi sopra citati?

Comment: Non capisco quale sia il problema sull’uso  del termine “evidenza” nelle frasi che hai evidenziato. Mi sembrano corrette e comprensibili.

Comment: Tra le tante sfumature citate da Treccani c’è anche: *certezza, chiarezza, limpidezza, (lett.) perspicuità, tangibilità, trasparenza, visibilità*... in che senso il termine non è adatto a quei contesti?

Comment: ...”Non c'è *un'evidenza* che ci dica che chi è stato infetto non possa fare dopo il vaccino...” : *chiarezza,  certezza*...

Comment: Non penso che l’ *evidence* inglese abbia influenzato l’ *evidenza* italiana, o perlomeno qualcuno dovrebbe fornire dell’evidenza in merito.  Evidenza è un termine abbastanza comune https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evidenza%2C+evidenze&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, ma "prova scientifica" non è esattamente lo stesso di  "chiarezza".       Perlomeno in catalano "evidence" e "evidència" usato in contesti scientifici al posto di "prova" sono considerati come dei falsi amici. Non è lo stesso in italiano? Non si dovrebbe dire "qualcuno dovrebbe fornire delle prove in merito"? Poi, guarda quello che ha detto DaG sulle [norme editoriali della rivista *Le scienze*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/richiedono-le-espressioni-%c3%88-unevidenza-che-e-%c3%88-di-tutta-evidenza-che-il-con#comment32812_13463).

Comment: Un’evidenza è qualcosa che evidenzia, cioè  mette in luce, in risalto qualcos’altro confermando le attese. Non avevo capito che la tua domanda fosse relativa  al gergo scientifico

Comment: @DaG: Sarebbe molto interessante se potessi riportare cosa dicono esattamente al riguardo le 
norme editoriali per collaboratori e traduttori della rivista *Le Scienze*. Io ricevo a casa ogni mese la rivista *Investigación y ciencia*, che è l'equivalente in spagnolo, ma, purtroppo, non ho accesso a tali norme per i traduttori in spagnolo degli articoli di *Scientific American*.

Comment: @Hachi, la definizione “classica” di “evidenza” è un termine astratto, non numerabile, all'incirca equivalente, come dici tu stesso, a “chiarezza, perspicuità” etc. Non possiamo dire che ci sono varie chiarezze a sostegno dell'efficacia di un farmaco. Non c'è “una” chiarezza, o tre, o tante, e lo stesso vale in origine per “evidenza”.

Comment: @Charo: Come accennavo altrove, le norme della rivista _Le Scienze_ hanno varie sezioni (su come usare le maiuscole, le virgolette etc.), due delle quali sono “Parole ed espressioni da non usare MAI…” (come per esempio “‘decadi’ al posto di decenni”) e “…e da usare il meno possibile”, tra cui appunto “evidenza (al posto di ‘prova’)”.

Comment: @Charo: L'unico problema di questa domanda è l'aspetto del “dovremmo”. Non saprei come modificarla, ma così suona lievemente _opinion-based_. _Is_ rispetto a _ought_ è spesso preso proprio come contrapposizione tra scienza – che è dimostrabile, verificabile – e morale (in senso lato), che si basa in ultima analisi su presupposti più o meno arbitrari.

Comment: @DaG: Ho cercato di attenuare quella domanda (non so se si possa dire così), ma non so se sono riuscita a farlo.

Comment: @DaG: Cercando argomenti per convincere un mio collega di lavoro (insegnante di catalano) a dire "proves" invece di "evidències" ho continuato a ricercare fonti. Allora mi sono imbattuta in questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/-possibile-emevidenziareem-le-emevidenzeem-storia-e-fortuna-di-un-calco-anglicizzante/2785).

Comment: @Hachi: Se t'interessa, dai un'occhiata all'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca che ho linkato nel mio commento precedente.

Comment: Io dico che questo è un anglicismo, cioè l'uso in italiano della parola inglese "evidence", che in questo caso è un "falso amico".

Comment: @Fabio: A dire il vero, nell'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca citato sopra c'è una risposta molto completa a questa domanda: là si trova tutto quello che ho chiesto spiegato con molti dettagli. Sentitevi liberi di usarlo come fonte per scrivere una risposta (io adesso non ho tempo di farlo e, veramente, ho già chiarito tutti i miei dubbi). Grazie a tutti del vostro impegno!

Comment: @DaG: Questo commento fa riferimento al catalano: per la lingua italiana c'è una risposta molto completa nell'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca. Sono stata al Gran Teatre del Liceu a sentire (e guardare) l'opera *Lessons in Love and Violence* di George Benjamin, che mi è piaciuta tantissimo. È stata una grandissima esperienza dopo tanto tempo che non si è potuto godere dell'opera in vivo. [Segue]

Comment: Nel testo di Martin Crimp appare qualche volta la parola "evidence" e mi ha rallegrato vedere che i soprattitoli in catalano la traducevano sempre come "proves" in plurale. In particolare, a un certo momento un personaggio fa la domanda "What evidence you have?": è stata tradotta come "quines proves tens?", che in italiano sarebbe "che prove hai?" o "quali prove hai?"

Comment: @DaG: L'unico è che, se ho capito bene l'articolo della Crusca, in italiano questo uso di "evidenza" è diffuso soprattutto nel lessico delle scienze della vita. Invece, in catalano, posso assicurare per la mia esperienza professionale che "evidència" usato con questo significato è anche molto diffuso nell'ambito dell'educazione.